# reading files in a batch does not read them correctly

Tags: r, file

I have 30 .txt files that I need to read to a tibble. Its panel data and altogether 108M

The issue is that some files are read correctly with all values there, but some read as NA while values are there! Also, files include a lot of blank lines....

Here is what I use:

```
read_clean_table<-function(x){
    x<-read.table(x, header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    x[-(1:4),] #first 4 rows are system data
  }

filenames<-list.files(path="./ML", pattern = ".*.txt", full.names=TRUE)

#read files and merge to table, first rows removed, FileName is the name of file
files<-filenames%>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_df(read_clean_table, .id = "FileName")%>%
  mutate(FileName=str_replace_all(basename(FileName), pattern="\\.txt",""))
```

I tried read.delim as well with the same success...

THis is what the issue looks like

[image]

edited:

added two files

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gDss6qV9aFUMpJFGHPMQZbTITJ9av-py?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you provide first few rows of atleast two files using which we can reproduce the issue that you are facing?

Comment: added a link to two files, ty

Comment: There are no common column names between the two dataframes hence you get NA for later values. What is your expected output ? Are those column names relevant?